# Google cloud iam unrecognized arguments when trying to create a key

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, service-accounts

I am trying to configure a google cloud service for a school assignment but when I try to run the command:

```
gcloud iam service-accounts keys create key.json -iam-account quickstart@ivannearshorepractice194420.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

ivannearshorepractice being the name of my project I get the following error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.iam.service-accounts.keys.create) unrecognized arguments:
  -iam-account
  quickstart@ivannearshorepractice194420.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

What is the cause and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry! It turns out my assignment instructions had a typo and the command is missing an extra dash before -iam-account :P
The correct command:

```
gcloud iam service-accounts keys create key.json --iam-account quickstart@ivannearshorepractice194420.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

If anyone has similar problems here is the reference:
https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys

Comment: Make sure that you always read errors ;) - `ERROR: (gcloud.iam.service-accounts.keys.create) unrecognized arguments:
  -iam-account`